# How to get the xpath of expand/collapse programmatically

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to determine if an object is expanded or collapsed programmatically in selenium using xpath selector.

```
<img class="action-icon ng-class:((vm.editMode &amp;&amp; vm.editAction == action) ? 'edit-expanded' : 'edit-collapsed' ) edit-collapsed" ng-src="*********">
```

So, I need to return true if the selenium xpath returns 'edit-expanded' or false 'edit-collapsed'

Comment: Can you please share more HTML code so I can provide you exact xpath. As Abel said right now I have mention //img which can return your all img tags on the page.

Comment: I have updated my answer which can match your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends that your the certain text'edit-expanded' and 'edit-collapsed' is present or not in class in img tag

If 'edit-expanded' and 'edit-collapsed'both will present then below xpath give you false and if only 'edit-expanded' only present then it gives you true

```
boolean( //img[contains(@class,'edit-expanded') and not(contains(@class,'edit-collapsed'))])
```

If both are present and below xpath return true. if any one is not present then it return false

```
boolean( //img[contains(@class,'edit-expanded') and contains(@class,'edit-collapsed')])
```

If you want separate xpath then below are the xpath. They return according to there presence in your img->class

```
boolean( //img[contains(@class,'edit-expanded')])

boolean( //img[contains(@class,'edit-collapsed')])
```

Comment: Please not that these will return true for any `img` in the whole document. If that is not wanted, either set the current node to something other than the root, or specify with an extra predicate what `img` you want to check.

Comment: you are right @Abel .. I will ask OP to share more info regarding there HTML code so we can set the current note to something other than the root. Thanx mate for your helpful suggestion :)